# My code keeps breaking because of something related to `:Clone()`

Tags: lua, roblox

I keep getting errors for my script whenever I test my code. This code is supposed to make a viewmodel in Roblox appear when you're in first person including secondary (havent worked on secondary yet). Here is my code :

```
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local char = player.Character or player.CharacterAdded:Wait()

local uis = game:GetService("UserInputService")
local rs = game:GetService("RunService")

local cam = game.Workspace.CurrentCamera

local framework = {
    inventory = {
        "AR-15";
        "G17";
        "Knife";
        "Frag"
    };
    
    module = nil;
    viewmodel = nil;
    
}

function loadSlot(item)
    local vmfolder = game.ReplicatedStorage.viewmodels
    local modulefolder = game.ReplicatedStorage.Modules
    
    if modulefolder:FindFirstChild(item) then
        framework.module = require(modulefolder:FindFirstChild(item))
        
        if modulefolder:FindFirstChild(item) then
            framework.viewmodel = vmfolder:FindFirstChild(item):Clone()
            framework.viewmodel.Parent = cam
        end
    end
end

rs.RenderStepped:Connect(function()
    for i,v in pairs(cam:GetChildren()) do
        if v:IsA("Model") then
            v:SetPrimaryPartCFrame(cam.CFrame)
        end
    end
end)

loadSlot(framework.inventory[1])`
```

I tried cleaning up my code and changing up some variables. I was expecting it to show the viewmodel, but instead it wouldn't show up and just give me "03:39:31.393  Players.no_cone3thesecond.PlayerScripts.FrameworkClient:30: attempt to index nil with 'Clone'  -  Client - FrameworkClient:30" in the console.

Comment: With no context/Roblox knowledge, seems like the inner if statement was intended to test `vmfolder:FindFirstChild(item)` rather than retesting `modulefolder:FindFirstChild(item)`. Testing this will presumably stop you from trying to `Clone` a nil value (but no idea if this will accomplish your ultimate goal).